# I can't make the size of my graph bigger using matplotlib.pyplot and using plt.figure(figsize = (10, 12))

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

how can  fix this.
my code:

```
plt.plot(kobe.Year, kobe['2P'], label = '2points made')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('2 points made')
plt.title('Kobe Bryant 2points made in his career')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 12))
```

this does not work

Comment: You must show us the problem, like some error code. `'How can I fix'` - How do we know what to fix if you don't tell us how `'this does not work'`.

Comment: put `plt.figure` line on top.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify first your plot's size and other arguments such as edge color, style etc.
So:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 12))   # remove last line and put it here
plt.plot(kobe.Year, kobe['2P'], label = '2points made')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('2 points made')
plt.title('Kobe Bryant 2points made in his career')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```